# Insert html form data into database

Tags: html

How to store a **html table** data into **MySQL database**.

Sample Html code is given below. In original, there is about thousand form on the same page.

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th> Id</th>
    <th>From area</th>
    <th>To area</th>
    <th>Basic price</th>
</tr>
</thead>   
<form action="basicprice.php" method="get" name="basicprice">
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="static">Address 1</td>
    <td class="static">Airport 1</td>
    <td class="center"><input type="text" name="basicprice" value="54"></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
</tr>                                     
</form>
<form action="basicprice.php" method="get" name="basicprice">
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="static">Address 1</td>
    <td class="static">Airport 1</td>
    <td class="center"><input type="text" name="basicprice" value="54"></td>
    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
</tr>
```

I want create a database from these details. Need Help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You wanna store the `<form>` structure in Database? Why?

Comment: you can use array please try reading array documnetaion if you are a starter.

Comment: no no. this is the html I have. I want store the value which is in td tags and textbox. I can't do it manually because there are thousands of same snippets are there @PraveenKumar

Comment: Is value is same for all it will keep on changing for every form..?

Answer (score 1):

Use only one form and add input feild name as `array[]`

```
<form action="basicprice.php" method="get" name="basicprice">
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="static">Address 1</td>
    <td class="static">Airport 1</td>
    <td class="center"><input type="text" name="basicprice[]" ></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
</tr>                                     
</form>
```

In this array you will get all values no need to write forms again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on bellow link
"[PHP - Insert data from HTML table into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908662/php-insert-data-from-html-table-into-mysql-database)" might give you some idea on how to make insert query using array elements